# Handling large files with Flysystem

Tags: php, symfony, flysystem

I'm using Flysystem in a Symfony app to manage files upload / download on S3.

```
$downloadableFileStream = $this->get("filesystem")->readStream($document->getDocument()),
$mimeType = $this->get("filesystem")->getMimetype($document->getDocument()),
$filename =$document->getDocument()

if (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
return new StreamedResponse(function () use ($downloadableFileStream, $mimeType, $filename) {
    fpassthru($downloadableFileStream);
}, 200, [
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary',
    'Content-Type' => "application/octet-stream",
    'Content-Disposition' => ('attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'),
    'Content-Length' => fstat($downloadableFileStream)['size'],
]);
```

It's really slow for large files, i was thinking using stream does not put all file in memory, maybe i'm doing something wrong ? (i have the same problem with upload, i'm using putStream).

The download is instant for small files, but for large files, it seems the complete file is loaded in the filesystem before launch download.

Is there any way to "start" the download not get the entiere file ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add `flush();` after `fpassthru($downloadableFileStream);`

so it will look like

```
fpassthru($downloadableFileStream);
flush();
```

Also you don't need `$mimeType` and `$filename` in use

Comment: it's the same, for a 3mo file, the new page opens wait 5 seconds, et the file is instantly available.

i need to start the download, like if i use a direct URL (but i can't because this bucket is private)

Comment: @BenjaminB. what about a webserver? maybe it is also buffering output?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean that PHP could work fine, but webserver also buffering putput (nginx or apache whatever you use)

Comment: i disabled nginx proxy_buffering off;  and it's the same :)

Comment: i fixed the problem temporary by get file from direct S3  secured private URL.

maybe what i want to do is impossible